# How to remove double square brackets from each rows of dataframe and data should not convert into string or list in python

Tags: python, list, dataframe, square-bracket

As you can see in image I want to remove all square brackets from Problem column

[image: As you can see in image I want to remove all square brackets from Problem column]

```
df["Problem"].astype(str).replace('[','',regex=True).astype(str).replace('\]','',regex=True)
```

**Note:** *By using upper code getting output is in string* **like "G,A,W"** *but required output should be* **like G,A,W**

Comment: have you tried the `df["Problem"].str.strip()` method? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html

Comment: yes, I tried but when I'm doing df.iloc[0,2] it's returning "'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'" but I want 'A','B','C','D'

Comment: what about replacing `' '` with `''`?

Comment: You might need to add another `.replace('"','')`

Comment: @RaymondKwok using `.str.strip()` with no arguments removes white space.

Comment: guys is it possible to get output like this 'A','B','C','D'